# How to find the roots of the polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

We consider the irreducible polynomial $g=y^4+y+1 \in \mathbb{F}_2[y]$ and let $b$ be a root of $g$.

I want to find all the roots of $g$ and also three generators of $\mathbb{F}_{16}^{\ast}$ as for the basis $\{1, b, b^2, b^3 \}$.
I have tried the following:
I applied the euclidean division of $y^4+y+1$ with $y-b$ and I got $y^4+y+1=(y-b) (y^3+by^2+b^2 y+(b^3+1))$.

Then I applied the euclidean division of $y^3+by^2+b^2 y+(b^3+1)$ with $y-(b+1)$ and I got $y^3+by^2+b^2 y+(b^3+1)=(y-(b+1))(y^2+y+(b^2+b+1))$.

Then suppose that the third root is $r_1$. Then applying the euclidean division of $y^2+y+(b^2+b+1)$ with $y-r_1$ we get $y^2+y+(b^2+b+1)=(y-r_1)(y+(1+r_1))$ when $r_1^2+r_1+b^2+b+1=0$.

How can we solve the last equation to get $r_1$? Can we use the discriminant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $ b $ is a root of $ g $, then so are $ b+1, b^2, b^2 + 1 $. All of these are obviously pairwise distinct since $ g $ is an irreducible polynomial.

EDIT : $ b^2 $ is a root because we have $$ g(b^2) = (b^2)^4 + b^2 + 1 = b^8 + b^2 + 1 = (b+1)^2 + b^2 + 1 = 0 $$ From the fact that $ b $ is a root $ \implies $ $ b + 1 $ is a root, we get that $ b^2 + 1 $ is also a root.

To answer your second question, you want to find a generator for $ \mathbb{F}_{16}^{\times} \cong \mathbb{F}_2(b)^{\times} $. We know that $ b^{15} = 1 $. Further, $ b^3 \neq 1 $, $ b^5 = b^2 + b \neq 1 $, so the order of $ b $ is indeed $ 15 $ and hence it is a generator for the multiplicative group. How then, can you find all other generators?

Comment: How can we show that $b^2$ and $b^2+1$ are roots? How did you find these roots?

Comment: I added more details. When you're working over fields like $ \mathbb{F_2} $, such observations help.

Comment: So can we just observe that $b^2$ is a root by substituting it at the polynomial?

Comment: Yes, some motivation for trying this is the fact that in fields of characteristic $ p $, we have $ (a+b)^p = a^p + b^p $. In more sophisticated language, over finite fields, the Frobenius Map is an automorphism.

Comment: Yes, you show that something is a root of a polynomial $f(x)$ by substituting it for $x$ and seeing whether the result is zero.

Comment: "All of these are obviously pairwise distinct since $g$ is an irreducible polynomial." This is correct, but only because $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a perfect field.  An easier way to see this is that $g' = 4y + 1 = 1$, so $g$ and $g'$ are relatively prime, hence $g$ has distinct roots.

Comment: $b+1$ is a generator since its order is $15$. How can we find an other generator. Do we check $b^2$ or $b^2+1$ ?